# Eclipse CVS repository properties issue

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

When I'm using Team Commit on my checked out code, its asking for some other credentials and creating a repository in the CVS repositories tab. I discarded the CVS repository. But when I try Team Commit again the same thing is happening.
Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Team Commit always requires a repository for whichever source control system you are using. So are you using CVS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Disconnect option on the projects in your workspace. This will erase the CVS metadata and should prevent this prompt.